# Problem finalizing Ubuntu installing. Please help

Tags: system-installation, 14.10

PROBLEM: I manage to get half-way through the installation process; I click install Ubuntu alongside Windows (I have an 80Gb SSD that will be used for Ubuntu, and a 1TB HDD that contains my windows) then after it shows me that Ubuntu will take up roughly 40GBs unpacked I am left with 38GBs ~ left. Then BOOM it tells me I don't have anymore free space and the installer just hangs for a while and then it shows me a pie chart/directory....?
I don't know if this matters but It doesn't let me use the "try Ubuntu" feature.. If I click on it it just it restarts the installing process and takes me to square one.
Any ideas as to why this is happening?..
Extra info: AMD cpu, gtx 760 SC, 12gb of ram and Windows 8.1 running default.
I created a live USB using the LiLi live USB creator to make a Bootable USB...
Like stated above everything goes smoothly up until that point, I've been reading up for weeks/already had another 1765 issues just trying to get Ubuntu to boot and then I had a run in with a bug that causes the installation to fail when it can't detect a HHD..
ANYWAYS, any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into something like that a few times, and nearly always it is the result of the install disk being flawed.  Sometimes the downloaded ISO is corrupted.  Sometimes the cd/dvd which is burned is flawed.  Sometimes writing the ISO image to flash media goes wrong.

I recommend you start over with a fresh copy of the OS to be installed.  While you are at it I have one more tip for you if you prefer safety and don't mind opening your PC to ensure a desirable result.  Please consider opening your PC and physically disconnecting the 1tb drive containing your windows installation while installing Ubuntu to the 80gb.  This way neither drive can be overwritten.  Later when both drives are connected, there's about a 60% chance that GRUB will offer up both operating systems as though you had a typical dual boot.  If that is not the case, reinstalling grub is EASY, and can be accomplished either of a couple of easy ways.

My reason for giving you that added advice is to help save you from a circumstance in which you might not be able to boot your PC to EITHER operating system, and also to help prevent your Windows installation from being accidentally overwritten.

Comment: And take the "Something else" option in the "Installation type" screen and define it yourself...

Comment: @Fabby...  I'm not sure what part of my ANSWER you are commenting on, and I'm not sure it applies.  Did you mean to comment to the question?

Comment: Well, you're saying the exact thing I would have told GMANZ, but I would have added what I just added to the comment too! so yes, it's in response to his question, but also in response to your response. Is it a comment or is it an answer??? I don't know either...  ;)

Comment: @fabby, my issue with your suggestion is that it detracts from my "leave well-enough alone" rule and hope that the user doesn't screw it up.  I'm already concerned because he apparently preformatted the Ubuntu partition in NTFS in preparation for his installation.  I even considered suggesting he not do that this time but accept all the defaults.  By suggesting he try "something else", I feel that only increases the chances he'll do something (else) ill-advised.

Comment: Mmmh...  I have to agree with you on that one...  Too bad there is no way to delete comments... P.S. where can I get mubuntustick? (google search returns zilch)

Answer (score 0):

Well one big mistake you are making is that if you are installing Ubuntu on an SSD and Windows is on a different HDD all together, they are **NOT being installed side by side**.

Side by side installation is intended for installing two operating systems on the **same disk.**

What you are describing is very possible, install Ubuntu like a normal OS and update GRUB to see Windows on the other hard drive.

Comment: I understand that; I know that the side-by-side installation should be the TWO partitions in one HDD. but After choosing that opting from the installer it only shows my SSD, presumably because I formatted it as NTFS in preparation for the install. Separate question: is it possible to make a Bootable USB without a third-party program like LiLi, I am asking because reducing the amount of variables could help me ensure that there are less chances of the process going wrong.